# Javascript onclick Tab into text box

Tags: javascript, html

When you click inside the textbox a window opens. How do you get the same effect if you use the tab button on the keyboard from another textbox into the one in question?

Javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function openwindow()
    {
    window.open('foo.php', 'newwindow', 'width=xxx,height=xxx,scrollbars=yes');
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input name="test" id="test" type="text" onclick="location.href='javascript:openwindow()';" target="_blank" size="12">
```

Comment: replace `onClick` to `onFocus`

Answer (score 0):

Try **onFocus**

```
<input name="test" id="test" type="text" onFocus="location.href='javascript:openwindow()';" target="_blank" size="12">
```

Comment: Legend! Sorry for the noob question. Hacking away!

Comment: @user2720970 Are you want to get this kind of output http://jsfiddle.net/w48U5/1/

Comment: @user2720970 onFocus function it will open window multi times. So my advice is go with the onClick function Check this http://jsfiddle.net/A57NR/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see what you mean by it opening again. Any way get around this? Is it possible to simulate a return key after the submit?